# How To Install New Android Apps without Uninstalling Other Installed Apps?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, uninstallation

I'm using Android 8.1.0 on my latest Huawei smartphone.
I'm constantly using several apps at a time & installing new ones as required..
but this problem (a sort of nuisance) is that I need to uninstall older installed apps just to download the new one. 
Is there any solution to fix that?
2nd problem I face, an app(of say 5 mb) requires up to 180mb space to be installed & that much amount of apps(& their spaces) needs to be emptied.
Is there any solution to fix that even?

Comment: its getting in my calmly nerves...

Comment: This is not a normal case since a user can always install a new app, provided there's a sufficient free space. Thus, looks like the issue is about low free storage space? Some apps (including most of modern apps) only installs the base app & resource to reduce the space, but then downloads more data/resources to run properly.

Comment: You need to buy a device with ample storage, preferably 64GB or more in size, or a device that supports an external SD card and re-location of apps to SD card.